# Reduce the network traffic priority in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, tc, traffic-shaping

I want to reduce the priority of specific network traffic using [`tc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) in particular [`tc-u32`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-u32.8.html) in my Linux server. In other words all other traffic must have higher priority than traffic with specified IP-proto.

I'm trying to apply this tc filter rule to make outgoing ICMP traffic lower priority:

```
tc f a dev eno1 parent 1: prio 2 u32 match ip protocol 1 0xff
```

But it returns this error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
We have an error talking to the kernel
```

Here are some things are still unclear to me about tc in this context:

1. How to make this rule work properly?
2. Do I need some another rule to tell Linux something like *"all other traffic goes with 1 priority"* or this is done by default?
3. What is the basic logic behind such naming - `1:`, `2:`, etc.? What does `0xff` mean? Should I explicitly specify `classid` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done the way I describing below.

First we should change the root discipline of interface (usually `pfifo_fast`) with the `prio` one:

```
tc q a dev eno1 root handle 1: prio
```

This command creates qdisc on `eno1` with `3` classes by default (`1:1` - the highest priority, `1:2` - middle, `1:3` - the lowest priority). Normally all the regular traffic goes to `1:2`, the traffic with the highest priority (e.g. through [ToS/DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service)) goes to `1:1`.
We can check the result via:

```
tc -d -s class show dev eno1
```

Then we can add filter rule to direct all the traffic with *IP protocol = 1* to 3rd (lower priority) class:

```
tc f a dev eno1 parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip protocol 1 0xff flowid 1:3
```

`parent 1:` - this filter is attached to qdisc. Based on filter result qdisc decides to which class this traffic should be directed.
`prio 1` - this filter's priority (filters with a lower prio are used first - specifically in this case doesn't matter, because there is only one filter)
[`u32`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-u32.8.html) - traffic classifier
`match ip protocol 1 0xff` - triggering the filter when packets with IP-proto 1 arrive. `0xff` - is a bitmask for IP protocol match.
`flowid 1:3` - the class to be used.

You can initiate some ICMP traffic and watch the `Sent` results via:

```
watch -d -n1 'tc -d -s class show dev eno1'
```